# Trials Timer with Read and Write

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, matlab, matlab-guide

I am creating a GUI in Matlab that will read and write data to a text file based on the trial duration. The user will enter the number of trials and trial duration and 
then push the "start" button.

For example the user enters 5 trials at 10 seconds duration. While starting the 1st trial, I will need to read/write data continuously for 10 seconds, then stop and save the text file. This process will continue for the next 5 trials. Here is a brief code I tried to implement below.

How can I run both the timer for 10 seconds and simultaneously read/write data with that time limit?

Thanks in advance.

```
        % Get Number of Trials
        number_trials = str2double(get(handles.Number_Trials,'String'));
        % Get Trial Duration
        trial_duration = str2double(get(handles.Trial_Duration,'String'));

        % Timer Counter
        global timer_cnt
        timer_cnt = 0;

        global eye_data
        eye_data = 0;

        for i = 1:number_trials
            % Set Current Trial Executing
            set(handles.Current_Trial_Text,'String',num2str(i));

            % Set Text File Specifications
            data_fname = get(handles.Data_Filename_Edit_Text,'String');
            file_fname = '.dat';
            data_fname_txt = strcat(data_fname,file_fname);

            % Timer Object
            fprintf('%s\n','Timer Started');

            % Pauses 10 Seconds
            t = timer('TimerFcn','stat=false','StartDelay',10);

            start(t);

            stat = true;
            while(stat == true)
                disp('.');
                pause(1)
            end

            fprintf('%s\n','Timer Ended');
            delete(t);

        end
```

Comment: so.. what's your question?

Comment: @DangKhoa Editted Post with Question. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so let me make sure I understand: in your example, the user specifies the number of trials he wants, and the length of time per trial. Then, a timer will collect data until the time is up. It does this for `num_trials` times.

Comment: @DangKhoa Yes that is what I am trying to accomplish. I tried your answer (tic/toc) but that only executes for 10 seconds for 1 trials. How can do this "n" trials?

Comment: Wrap it in a for loop. I thought that would have been fairly obvious.

Comment: @DangKhoa I wrapped in a for loop, it completes the first trial in 10 seconds then executes the rest of trials iteratively. How can I reset tic/toc to 0 after completing each trial? Thanks.

Comment: How did you call it? `t_start = tic` needs to be inside your `for` loop to get reset. Basically the entire code snippet I posted should be in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, timers are usually used in the context of "wait this amount of time, then do `foo`" rather than how you're using it, which is "do `foo` until you've done it for this amount of time".

The humble [`tic/toc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) functions can do this for you.

```
t_start = tic;
while toc(t_start) < 10
    % do data collection
end
```

Comment: Note that you can either place both `tic` and `toc` in the loop, or compare `toc` with the required amount of seconds multiplied by your loop variable. `toc < 10 * i`. Also note that assigning `tic` to a variable and calling `toc` with this variable as input is optional.